# Prevent Zipping in VSBuild task in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines, .net-framework-version, azure-pipelines-yaml

I would like to copy Angular UI dist folder content into published content, specifically wwwroot when using VSbuild task as shown below

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

My two questions are

1. whether this task is responsible for publish that we do manually in Visual Studio, and hence can I expect wwwroot folder to be present in the corresponding target location?
2. How do I say zip : false in the above command so that I can copy the required content and then zip later?

Thanks,
AK

Comment: Hi there, I have updated my answer. Please check whether it can help you.

Comment: Sorry, I found that there was a mistake in my previous answer. I have updated my answer, hoping it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

> whether this task is responsible for publish that we do manually in Visual Studio, and hence can I expect wwwroot folder to be present in the corresponding target location?

Yes. You can use msbuild arguments to do this:

```
msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
```

Use `/p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem` to output the results as files, not a zip. Use `/p:publishUrl={target location}` to specify the output location.

> How do I copy the required content and then zip later?

Add the following script to your `.csproj` file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="wwwroot\**" CopyToOutputDirectory="drop" />
  </ItemGroup>
```